# Rust: Struct generic type parameter for use in Fn member signature requires named lifetime

Tags: rust, lifetime

I have a struct with function member:

```
struct Foo<T> {
    fun: Box<dyn Fn(T)>,
}

type FooI = Foo<&mut i32>;
```

This doesn't work:

```
error[E0106]: missing lifetime specifier
 --> src/main.rs:5:17
  |
5 | type FooI = Foo<&mut i32>;
  |                 ^ expected named lifetime parameter
  |
help: consider introducing a named lifetime parameter
  |
5 | type FooI<'a> = Foo<&'a mut i32>;
```

But I don't want FooI to be parameterised for the lifetime of T, I just want instances of T to outlive the call to Foo.fun. How would I encode that?

Comment: I think the compiler has given you the correct suggestion. It dosent bind `T` to any lifetime. All it is doing is creating an alias to `Foo<&'a mut i32>`. You can set the `'a` lifetime later to specify how long the `i32` reference needs to live for when you use `FooI` somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately what you're trying to do won't currently work with Rust. When a struct is generic over a reference that reference will have to live for at least the life of the struct. So, if you listened to the compiler it wouldn't do what you wanted: 
[playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=91ef8e1a300319bdcbf72525744b6cd9)

Because of this you either have to make `fun` be `Box<dyn Fn(&mut T)>` or change your struct to be generic over anything.

```
struct Foo<T> {
    fun: Box<dyn Fn(&mut T)>
}

type FooI = Foo<i32>;
```

[Playground Link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=80969529a673fd886a107da418fbadaa)

I haven't seen the code in context, but this might be a good chance to use [traits](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch10-02-traits.html).